# What are the ewok costumes made from?

Tags: star-wars, costume

I saw a post on [SF&F](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/977/what-type-of-hair-was-used-in-the-construction-of-chewbaccas-costume-in-the-sta) on Chewbacca's costume which is made from yak and mohair hair but then wondered what the Ewoks' costumes were made from as they don't look like the same material.

Comment: *"What are the ewok costumes made from?"* Wookie pelts.

Answer (score 1):

### Some type of fake fur

A listing for an offcut of an Ewok costume on [The Prop Gallery](http://www.thepropgallery.com/ewok-costume-offcut) describes the piece as 'fur':

> This is an offcut from one of the original Ewok costumes created by the make-up department headed by Graham, Kay and Stuart Freeborn, noted contributors to the Star Wars universe.
>
> This large offcut was surplus during the production process and to the rear **features an arrow to indicate the direction of the fur** and to the edges traces of white chalk where the section of material was marked out during the creation of the costume.
>
> The costume offcut measures approximatly 14.5" x 9" at its widest points and remains in excellent condition, it represents a much finer and more impressive example of original Ewok fur than the majority of smaller swatches available on the collectors market.

[image: Rear view of offcut]

[image: Front view of offcut]